# Cookie is set 2 times in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, cookies

I am trying to set cookie . The condition is if there is no cookie then create one or else delete the existing cookie and create a new cookie with defined values.
The code I am using is:-

```
var cook= getCookie("day");
var today = new Date();

              var day = today.getDate();
              var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
              var year = today.getFullYear();
              if (username == "") {
                  //document.cookie = "day" + '=' + day + '=;path=/';
                  //document.cookie = "month" + '=' + month + '=;path=/';
                  //document.cookie = "year" + '=' + year + '=;path=/';
                  document.cookie = "day" + '=' + day;
                  document.cookie = "month" + '=' + month;
                  document.cookie = "year" + '=' + year;
                  alert("blank");

              }
              else {

                  document.cookie = "day" + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
                  document.cookie = "month" + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
                  document.cookie = "year" + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
                  document.cookie = "day" + '=' + day;
                  document.cookie = "month" + '=' + month;
                  document.cookie = "year" + '=' + year;

                  alert("delCre");
                  var uname = getCookie("day");

              }
function getCookie(cname) {
                  var name = cname + "=";
                  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                      var c = ca[i].trim();
                      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                  }
                  return "";
              }
```

The problem is cookie is created  2 times. First cookie value for day , month, and year are same as I want. BUt for second, its taking old value.

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading - you are apparently setting the cookie  in JavaScript (client side) so I doubt this issue has anything to do with MVC (server side). You should really change it and your tags to get some help for JavaScript, not for MVC.

Comment: Not to mention that is probably not a good idea to set an auth cookie from javascript.